# How to Use Sub-Sets of Git Repo Files?

Tags: git, text, github, merge, bitbucket

I'm new to version control, but I'm quickly finding Git to be [a great way to manage my collection of writings](http://nocategories.net/ephemera/writing/useful-features-of-version-control-software/#comment-1065891148). This is a slightly unusual use case, so I have a question about which of Git's functions would be best to help me manage "collected" writings (i.e. the whole set) and to manage "selected" writings (i.e. sub-sets of the collection).

I have, for example, a repository that contains 200 .txt files. Each one is the text of a poem. Now, I'd like to set aside 20 of those files, for example, to create a manuscript. While I'm working with those 20 files and thinking of them as a group, I may make changes to them. I would like, of course, for those changes to be reflected in my "master" repository of all 200 files.

I've seen *a variety of approaches* that might work for this, and I'm confused.

1. The first thing I tried was a subfolder full of symlinks. That was lovely, until I realized Git on Windows doesn't handle symlinks well.
2. [a `branch` can handle this in a nice way, with help from `merge
   --strategy ours`](http://ask.metafilter.com/249100/Can-a-Git-Branch-Contain-Only-a-Sub-Set-of-the-Repository#3617407)
3. I might prefer a `submodule` though, since it would enable me to
   track issues for manuscript projects separately, and keep a related
   wiki, as a project on bitbucket or wherever. It might also make
   collaboration a little easier down the road. However, I hear that
   there are pitfalls to submodules. Will those prove to be a
   problem for me?
4. Then there's `subtree`. Would that be a better method for what I
   have in mind? Can subtrees or submodules use the same merge strategy that I like for branches?
5. Are there other, potentially better methods to consider?

Comment: Your solutions 1 and 2 look very reasonable. They should get you where you want.

Comment: Can 4 use the same merge strategy as 2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I may be missing the point. The raison d'etre of git is it's easy of branching. This essentially allows you to create a parallel line of work very simply.

But if you just create a branch off your master, collate your 20 or poems in a e.g. a folder, then commit to this new branch (maintaining your parallel universe of your 20 poems) then merge this into the master when you want these changes to be registered in your master branch.

```
$ git branch manuscript
$ git checkout manuscript

$ mkdir my20poems
$ cp *.poems my20poems

$ git add my20poems
# make your changes, now commit them in my commit graph 
$ git commit -m "did some work"
# now I want these changes in master
$ git checkout master
$ git merge manuscript  #or even use the --no-ff switch if you want the branch history kept
```

you can always revisit any of your prior commits so all your commited states will be preserved.

```
$ git log --oneline --decorate --graph --all
```

Comment: While this method would work (and it nicely avoids the trouble of having to delete lots of files in the branch), wouldn't the end result be multiple copies of a poem, one for each time it has appeared in a manuscript? That isn't ideal in my case.

Comment: OK, git doesn't store duplicates of objects if they have the same SHA1 hash: http://git-scm.com/book/en/Getting-Started-Git-Basics.

Comment: You could probably achieve the same effect as "--strategy ours" by copying the changed files over manually to the master rather than merging, I think this would give you a similar effect and a simpler history. However if you are determined to consider the master and manuscript as distinct entities in their own right then you should put them in as submodules.

Comment: ultimately, I decided to use `git branch` for this, after I learned more about, and became more comfortable with `git` in general. marking this as the answer.